# Can Read-only ASP application/web-page recreate expired sessions and update them?

Tags: asp.net, session-state, session-cookies, session-timeout

I had a query on behavior of an ASP read only application using a custom Session State provider.
I assume, for a normal read-write application/web-page the session will be recreated after the expiry as long as the client has sent a session cookie. The runtime may opt to change the session identifier at this point, but it normally won't. What about Read-only applications? Do they follow the same behavior? If they are recreated, Can they update these sessions?

Thanks,
Alfan